# Side-effect-free functions and returning domain information DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, side-effect

In Domain-Driven Design (Eric Evans) the discussion on side-effect-free functions talks about separating **commands** which "result in modifications to observable state" from **queries** which have no side-effects.

Then there's this part (emphasis mine):

> Strictly segregate commands into very simple operations that **do not return domain information.**

What is the importance of not returning domain information in this context?

Comment: Returning domain information would be a *query.*

Comment: Another way to think about commands is to compare them to Updates, Deletes and Inserts when applied to a database. Those usually don't return you anything about the tables they changed except by "Changed X records" or something of the sort. Unless you do something very... exotic, it isn't common to do ask the database to a insert a new Employee record and be slapped back in the face with the last 25 employees named "John".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the importance of not returning domain information in this context?

It's a restatement of [Command Query Separation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html), proposed by Bertrand Meyer.

> Asking a question should not change the answer.

In particular, you shouldn't have to change the state of the program to ask a question about it.

> You’re not really answering why it is important not to return information from a command. If you think about it, it’s fairly obvious not to change state when doing a query, but why is it a bad practice for a command to return (new) state?

I think it's a classification issue: ie, by definition a method that returns a value *is* a query.  In other words, mechanics trumping semantics.

But perhaps this historical perspective will help.

In the late 90s, C++ was a popular language, and [exception safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) was an important design constraint -- how do you ensure recovery when transactions can fail?  When exceptions could not be eliminated from the design, the goal became strong exception safety: in the face of an exception, the program should rollback to a known good state.

One case where an exception could occur is during the *copy* of an object; we have some object that needs a lot of heap, try to copy that object, but there's not enough heap left to support a second instance.  BOOM.

Which meant that, in general, some operations could throw *when returning the result*.

[Riddle](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm): how to create an implementation of `T Stack<T>::pop()` that was strongly exception safe?

And the answer is... it cannot be done.  You modified the internal data structure of the stack to remove the desired element, the attempt to return the value throws, and you've got no way to put the stack back into its original state.

Instead, you had to [change the design](https://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html) of the stack api, so that you have better control of where the modifications of the stack actually happen relative to the dangerous copy.  For example

```
T Stack<T>::top() // Does not change the stack!
void Stack<T>::pop() // Does not perform a dangerous copy
```

Comment: You’re not really answering why it is important *not to return information from a command*. If you think about it, it’s fairly obvious not to change state when doing a query, but why is it a bad practice for a command to return (new) state?

Comment: @RikD Can you explain the difference between a "command" that returns state and a "query" that changes state?

Comment: The name of the method. You don’t expect a method called SearchUser to change state. A method called CreateUser, that returns the Id for the newly created user feels more reasonable.

Comment: @RikD The OP is asking about behavior, not how to name things. And while naming is important, it is the *behavior* of a method that we use as a means for classification. For example, if I saw a signature like `public void SearchUser(...)` I *would* assume state change (the assumption being the domain is concerned with storing search information). Similarly, given a signature like `public User CreateUser(...)` I would be more inclined to understand the method as a factory than a command.

Comment: Good explanation @king-side-slide. How do you handle commands that can fail? Throw an exception? I often use a Result for a command that can fail, because I’d like to reserve exceptions for truly exceptional situations. Do you think returning a Result for a command and a Result<T> for a query violates CQS?

Comment: @RikD I do not. `Result` does not (should not) represent domain information. The practice is better understood as a kind of shorthand for `try/catch` where the return value is wrapped instead of the calling code. There is very little conceptual difference between throwing exceptions and returning a `Result`. One either does a `try/catch` around `void` or `if/else` around `Result`. I see this as a matter of preference. Though... when I hear phrases like "truly exceptional" I can't help but wonder what a Scotsman would think.